# What is the difference between "setup" and "install" based on computer programs?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between “setup” and “install” based on computer programs?

According to Wikipedia search “setup” directly means “install” on computer.

**Edit:**

According to Wikipedia search "setup" does not directly means "install".  "setup" is just another word for “install" on computer.

> Installation **(or setup)** of a computer program **(including device
> drivers and plugins)**, is the act of making the program ready for
> execution. Because the process varies for each program and each
> computer, programs **(including operating systems)** often come with an
> installer, a specialized program responsible for doing whatever is
> needed for their installation.

but why we use two different words to describe one thing?

While in some cases (such as in Visual Basic 6 where you can create “setup.exe” of your program) “setup” used to define making a program execution ready but also in some cases (such as office programmes) “install” used instead of “setup”.

Are both 100% same or have slight differences?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Install* means to put a program on your computer. *Setup* can mean to configure the program, including various options, as in:

> I'm going to set up Word so that the grammar checker is turned off.

I would say that when you are *installing* a program, you are also performing its *initial setup*, so either word could be used in that context. Put another way, you can *set up* a program after it's been installed, but you can't *install* a program after it's been set up.

By the way, there seems to be a slight logic flaw in the wording of your question. You said:

> According to Wikipedia, *setup* directly means *install* on computer:
>
> > *Installation (or setup) of a computer program*...

I wouldn't say that the parenthetical "(or setup)" after the word "Installation" indicates that "setup **directly means** install". "Directly means" seems too strong an interpretaion for language. Instead, I would say:

> According to Wikipedia, *setup* is another word for *install*:
>
> > *Installation (or setup) of a computer program*...

The difference is slight, but subtle. My wording implies that, when installing a program, you could also use the word *setup* – but *setup* may have other meanings as well. Your wording seems to imply that *setup* is more of an exact synonym, with no other meanings.

I'd diagram the difference like this:

[image: "directly means" seems to imply too strong a correlation between definitions]

Put another way, I wouldn't say:

> The word *right* directly means *correct*.

because the word *right*, in addition to being the opposite of *wrong*, can also mean the opposite of *left*, or describe a 90-degree angle. That's why I'd say something more like:

> The word *right* can be used to mean *correct*.

In this case, I would say:

> The word *setup* can be used to mean *install.*

which is an accurate statement, and aligns with what you found in Wikipedia.

Comment: I really liked those graphs. Though it made me feel like idiot but a good explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. No need to feel silly about it, though. That's what we're here for – making very smart people just a little bit smarter!

Comment: It seems that to avoid the ambiguity of the words "setup" and "setting up", we can use "configuration" and "configuring" instead. (I'm just one of the students on this site. A student, not a teacher.)

Answer (score 1):

`Setup` is a **custom** `installation`!

Comment: Could you explain further?

Comment: For example, you download an **installer**, then **customize** the installation process based on your needs (**setup** it)!